# colorbox load with ajax results

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, lightbox, colorbox

Im using ajax to load content into a page, the content has colorbox lightbox buttons.

the light box opens for all static html buttons however does not open for the buttons which have been loaded into the page by ajax. could anybody help

```
$(".various").colorbox({opacity:0.7});
```

**//colorbox js**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**//Ajax Request**

```
<a href="page.php" class="various">Open Lightbox</a>
```

**//HTML Link**

Comment: I found this from another question but it didn't work $('a.yourlinkclass').live('click', function(){
  $.colorbox({href:"html_to_show.html"});
});

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery.live() is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Can you post your success method and any other relevant code.

Comment: You can use `.on()` instead of `.live()`

Comment: on and live work for jquery 1.7 but lightbox opens then closes and goes to the page it should be opening in the light box :-(

Comment: Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: to much to add to fiddle, thanks though